# Mouse stopped working on Ubuntu VM

Tags: virtualbox, mouse

I've been using Ubuntu 22.04.3 virtual machine on Windows 10 with VirtualBox 7.0.10 for some time and everything was good. But suddenly, the mouse stopped working properly. I can use the icons in the sidebar but I can't click on anything in opened windows. Interestingly, after opening a new app window, I can drag it but only once. If I try to do it again, nothing happens and I have to reopen the application. I have to close apps by right-clicking on their icons in the sidebar because I can't click the X button, among the others.

I've tried different solutions like:

- disabling and enabling Mouse Integration
- changing pointing device to PS/2 Mouse, USB Tablet or even USB Multi-Touch Tablet
- killing drag&drop processes
- unchecking Enable Nested Paging in Acceleration settings

but nothing helped. What else can I do?